# "void" problem: program to simulate a virus

Tags: c, void

i'm trying to simulate a virus for a school project. Basically, in a 50*50 matrix, called `island`
there are randomized things: there may be a person (`x`), if there is, he may be infected(`p`) or not. Then, they might get infected, if they don't use protections. Of course, they also might get immune by getting cures (`i`).
The "infecting" program is called `infecter()`; the immune one is called `medic()`.

Here comes the problem: the last program i call ( this happens with `infecter()`, `medic()`) will not do everything i want it to do. In fact, if the last is `medic()`, i won't be able to tell if i want to get medics in the island; if the last one is `infecter()`, it will infect, but i won't be able to tell if the people are using facemasks, ecc.

```
//INFECTER
void infecter()
{ //prog to infect ppl: if there are 2 pos close to the person, 50%; if there arent, 20%;
    //
    [... full of surely bad indented and still working stuff...]
}

//MEDIC
void medic()
{ //program to save ppl==> 25% of possiblities to get no longer virus'd
   [full of badly indented but working stuff]

    printf("\n***************************************************\n");
    //

   

    infecter();
    medic();
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

P.S.:
i worked like this, to create `void`s: i wrote code in `main()` function, and then copy pasted it into a `void` one, trying obviously to make it work.
Thanks to everyone who tries to help me...

EDITED:
as i saw comments that told me that this is too much code, i'll put it in another way.
`infecter()` and `medic()` surely work. They worked before this problem, and still do their job. The problem is: why don't they work completelly when they are called at the end of `main()` function?

EDITED PART TWO:
i'm shocked, everything works ok if i just put `medic()` before `infected()`. But then `medic()`wouldn't make sense (medics would help and save just rly little  infected, basically...)
so i tried to call it before and after, like this:

```
medic();
printf("\n");
infecter();
printf("\n");
fake();
printf("\n");
medic();
```

now `infecter()` doesn't work properly.

Comment: One of the first steps would be to indent your code properly

Comment: im sorry Cid, i don't really know. How could that be a problem?

Comment: It helps reading the code. For you and for the ones who'll see it

Comment: That is not causing the problem itself but poorly indented code may cause you or us to misread the code. If indentation does not match logical structure you can get misguided.

Comment: This is just too much code to comprehend what you're doing. But one thing I see is that you call functions "external programs", which is wrong. Please try to narrow down the problem, preferably by removing as much code as you can. Never write large parts of code in one go, write it in small and easily testable chunks.

Comment: How is `void` related to your problem. Also what is "a void"? Do you mean functions with return type `void`?

Comment: And as a new poster here, please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to [edit] your questions, and how to create a [mcve], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: Gerhardh, as im not sure what the real problem is, i thought it was about the `void` function i wrote

Comment: Some programmer dude yeah i know, sorry, pls comprehend also the fact that im new and this is my very first post. I tried to read the rules, but english isn't my language and google translate isn't exactly useful someimes..

Comment: The updated code you show will result in an infinite recursion. I really suggest you start over from scratch, by dividing up the problem you should solve into smaller and simpler sub-problems. Continue dividing up the sub-problems into even smaller and simpler sub-problems, until no problem can be divided any more. Then implement each little sub-problem one by one in your program. Testing and ***debugging*** (if you find a problem) between each bit.

Comment: This divide and conquer method not only makes it easier to implement, test and debug your program, but also makes it easier to understand the big problem itself.

Comment: some programmer dude: I've used scratch three years ago, so I know how to and will do as you say. But actually the question wasn't on how to write correctly the code, it was on why is everything  working, when I put it in an (illogical) order, and why isn't everything working, when I put it in the order I need it to be. Oh and also:what do you mean by saying "the code you show will result in an infinite recursion"? You mean that it will start an infinite loop???

Comment: The thing is that we really can't tell you, because either there's too much code or there's too little. The only one that can properly debug your code is yourself. And the best way to do that is to follow good coding principles from the very start. Or if you already have something large then try to scale back. But either way, the only way to solve your problem is to to actual debugging. Probably stepping through the code statement by statement in a debugger while monitoring variables and their values. Unfortunately it might not work if you have *undefined behavior*, hence rework or rescale.